# Use Html2Pdf in production mode (without useless files)

Tags: php, composer-php, html2pdf

I use html2pdf to generate my PDF but since version 5 we can not use it without composer

The problem is that it generates me 567 files and 45 files and that half of the files are totally useless as the examples

How to use only what interests me is to say the generation of PDF ?

I think I use composer correctly, I did :

```
composer require spipu/html2pdf
```

And after (in the folder) :

```
composer install --no-dev
```

I will have to go through all the folders and delete the files manually?

Comment: if you check the composer.json file you might be able to remove what you dont need,depends how its installed.

Comment: You need to report it to maintainer of this package - he should remove tests and examples from dist files by using `.gitattributes` and `export-ignore`.

Comment: @smith In my composer I only have this :    "require": {
        "spipu/html2pdf": "^5.1"
    }